# Bayes continuous case and a uniform marginal density

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Assume I have a population $A$ distrubuted Uniform $U[a, b]$ and now assume I have a Conditional probability distribution conditioned on $S$ given $A$ i.e. $f(S | A)$ where $S$ is a binary variable that can only assume 0 or 1.

Now if I want to find out the Conditional probability distribution of $f(A | S)$ I use Bayes rule that states: $f(A|S)= \frac{f(S|A) f(A)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(S|A)f(A) dA}$

Now in the uniform case since the PDF $f(A)$ is a constant. Can I cancel out $f(A)$ in the nominator and denominator?

Such that I only get: $f(A|S)= \frac{f(S|A)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(S|A) dA}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but beware of the integral limits, i.e. $[a,b]$. The uniform density was ensuring this bound, because it's $1/(b-a)$ only in $[a,b]$, and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the Integral limits in denominator should only be between $a$ and $b$ correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.